# How to implement Flash player in android is any API are available to implement it?

Tags: android

How to implement Flash player in android is any API are available to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player is currently available to Android 3.1 system. There is a flash installer available on android market. Give it a try [HERE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer&feature=search_result).

Comment: Thanks for Reply                                                              how to play the video using URL i tried with Video View it will not play all the vedios.

Comment: In there you must have now an application. The flash installer I posted is just for allowing the android to render flash videos

Comment: Can i use Flex along with Adobe Air SDK?

Answer (score 0):

There is now an official [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/). Very powerful though experimental API at present.